# Excel VBA Open File Error 1004 After prefixing "~$"

Tags: windows, excel, file, filesystems, vba

I am writing some VBA to optimise workflows in Excel 2013 and I am using a Windows 10 machine.
I use a simple recursive procedure to traverse the file structure looking for specific content in file names as per below:

```
Function filePathToList(fileStart As String, firstString As String, secondString As String) As String
Dim FileSystem As Object
Dim HostFolder As String

HostFolder = fileStart
Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

filePathToList = DoFolder(FileSystem.GetFolder(HostFolder), LCase(firstString), LCase(secondString))
End Function

Function DoFolder(Folder, firstString As String, secondString As String) As String
Dim SubFolder
For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
    DoFolder = DoFolder(SubFolder, firstString, secondString)
Next
Dim File
For Each File In Folder.Files
    If (InStr(1, LCase(File.name), firstString) > 0) And (InStr(1, LCase(File.name), secondString) > 0) Then
        DoFolder = Folder.Path & "\" & File.name
        Debug.Print DoFolder
        Debug.Print File.name
        Debug.Print File
        Exit Function
    End If
Next
End Function
```

I have made some debugging to figure out what happens, and I'll be d*mned but VBA decides to add "~$" as a prefix to my found file:

```
X:\05_Sputnik\T\Pony\_New_building_YYYYpp_\~$Komplettlista_Mamma mu.xlsx
~$Komplettlista_Mamma mu.xlsx
X:\05_Sputnik\T\Pony\_New_building_YYYYpp_\~$Komplettlista_Mamma mu.xlsx
```

The way I see it the complete path is:
X:\05_Sputnik\T\Pony_New_building_YYYYpp_\Komplettlista_Mamma mu.xlsx
And VBA agrees with me since it complains about not finding it when trying to open it.

I can solve this by doing a substring extraction but imo it's not very neat. My question is however;

**Why does this happen?**

I find the file exactly where it is expected to be and there are no hidden files with similar names. Is Windows playing a trick on me?

Comment: The `~$` files are just temporary locking files created when you open a workbook (or when someone else opens the workbook).  They should be deleted again when the workbook is closed, but sometimes they get left in existence if Excel crashes or something similar.  (Note: the temporary files are just dummy files, or maybe they contain the userid of who has the file open, but they are not Excel workbooks - so a `Open` of them will fail.)

Comment: Okay, so I take it when I iterate over each File in Folder.Files Windows is temporarily creating a lock for that file? Thus, when finding a match in the rest of the file name that's the name returned.

Comment: No - the lock file would only be created if the file is currently open in Excel (such as the file your macro is in), or was previously open in Excel but not closed correctly.  Your code is just iterating over the files in the directory without actually opening the files - so you should just be seeing the same files as you would if you looked at the folder in Windows Explorer (assuming WE has "show hidden files" enabled).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore hidden files (such as the lock files generated by Office applications when you open a document), it might be best to modify your line saying

```
If (InStr(1, LCase(File.name), firstString) > 0) And (InStr(1, LCase(File.name), secondString) > 0) Then
```

to also test that the file is not hidden, e.g.

```
If (InStr(1, LCase(File.name), firstString) > 0) And _
   (InStr(1, LCase(File.name), secondString) > 0) And _
   Not (File.Attributes And vbHidden) Then
```